# How to show Yes or No window in window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying warn user to save data if he wants leave the page. The message should display simple "Do want save the data?" , If YES call code behind method (asp:button click), if NO leave the page from the page.

But now It is showing Unwanted message string with my message (see below).

[image]

```
 var form_has_been_modified = 0;
    $(function () {

        $("input").keyup(function () {
            form_has_been_modified = 1;
        })
        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            if (!form_has_been_modified) {
                return;
            }

            var message = "Do you want to save the data before leave the page?";

            return message;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is the browser behavior and you cannot change it.
You may want to re-word your message so that it makes sense in the context of the browser's pre-defined message. Also, make sure you test other browsers, as the message and behavior may be different.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special behavior of Internet Explorer (as a client web browser), you can do nothing about it. It is a special box only for onbeforeunload(). If you show Yes/No dialog in other places of your JS, you will get normal box. But for onbeforeunload() you get such dialog.

In IE9 it was replaced with even more sophisticated box, which has "Leave page" and "Stay on page" buttons. This is done to protect users from fraud sites.